# Error: required: android:support.v4.FragmentManager, found: android.app.FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

```
 FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
```

It is giving the error

> required : android:support.v4.FragmentManager
>   found: android.app.FragmentManager

I am using API 15

Comment: use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`

Answer (score 7):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()`, or change the `import` for `FragmentManager` from what you have (`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`) to `android.app.FragmentManager`.

You need to consistently use either the native classes or the backport. You cannot mix and match.

Answer (score 3):

add these two import

```
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

for example

```
   FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.id_parent_fragment,fragmentA);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

consider FragementA is the fragment that you want to insert in the activity which in this case is the container in the activity id_parent_fragment

Answer (score 1):

change the import of Fragment Activity below

```
 import android.support.app.FragmentActivity;
```

to

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me for creating fragment with `viewpager`.

Make your activity extend `AppCompatActivity()`, then use `supportFragmentManager`.

```
abstract class YourActivity() : AppCompatActivity() { /*your Activity Code*/ }
```

Then, when creating your `viewpager` with fragment:

```
 val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
 viewPager.adapter = adapter
 sliding_tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```